# Integrate facebook credits in facebook apps

Tags: facebook

I want to Integrate facebook credits in my fb apps. I downloaded sample code from referral site but that is not working.

My app link is `apps.facebook.com/football_leagues` and from `fan$` link when you click at redeem , a popup window opens for credits. But I get an error message:

> There was an error making your Facebook Credits purchase.
>   Order::update_order called with invalid state transition:3 -> 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is here: http://developers.facebook.com/credits and there's a sample (PHP) application included with the SDK.
The sample application can be retrieved from github here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/

The technical docs are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already visited these links and also download sample code from referral site but that is not working.
my app link is https://apps.facebook.com/football_leagues and from fan$ link when you click at redeem then a popup window open for credits but give error There was an error making your Facebook Credits purchase. Order::update_order called with invalid state transition:3 -> 0
Please send if you have any example code

Comment: I think your callback isn't working correctly, 3 is 'PLACED' and 0 is not a valid option, you may be using an empty or uninitialised value in your code when updating the order status - I presume this is in the code to mark an order as settled when you recieve the callback?

Comment: can you send me the correct code for callback.php
because me facing this problem from many days and my project deadline is near to close today.

Comment: When I click at buy item then me getting this error
Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. You have not been charged for this transaction. Please try again.

Comment: Any updated on above i am passing {"method": "payments_status_update", "content": [{"order_id": 250094715065199, "status": "settled" }]} at buy now and getting error Order::update_order called with invalid state transition:3 -> 0